# How to define a lambda function to be able to capture the 'this' pointer of a class?

Tags: c++, lambda, this, capture, arduino-esp32

I have a time class which tracks the time.

I want my other classes to be able to register a callback function if the day changes.

I have this working snippet:

```
#define MAX_CB_CHANGE_FUNCTIONS 50
typedef void (*dayChangeFunc)(int prevDay,int nowDay);

class TimeSystem {
    private:
        // array for the function pointers.
        dayChangeFunc dayChangeFunctions[MAX_CB_CHANGE_FUNCTIONS];
        // emit function if the day changes.
        void emitDayChange(int prev, int now);
    public:
        void regDayChange(dayChangeFunc);
};


/*
*   Registering a day change function.
*   Maximum function pointer count is MAX_CB_CHANGE_FUNCTIONS ( see timeSys.h )
*/
void TimeSystem::regDayChange(void (*dayChangeFunc)(int prevDay,int nowDay)){
    if( currDayCbIndex >= MAX_CB_CHANGE_FUNCTIONS ){
        if(isDebugOn){
            debug.print(DEBUG_WARN,"[Time_sys] - Can not register an other day change function.\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    dayChangeFunctions[currDayCbIndex] = dayChangeFunc;
    currDayCbIndex++;
}

/*
*   Emitting day change to every registered function.
*/
void TimeSystem::emitDayChange(int prev, int now){
    // Preventing change on initialization.
    if( prev == 0 ){ return; }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_CB_CHANGE_FUNCTIONS; i++){
        if(dayChangeFunctions[i]){
            dayChangeFunctions[i](prev,now);
        }
    }
}
```

**This works and other calsses can use this like this:**

```
timeSys.regDayChange([](int prevDay,int nowDay){
    Serial.printf("Day changed from prev: %d to now: %d\n",prevDay,nowDay);
});
```

**Now i want to capture the 'this' pointer in the lambda to be able to call some internal function of a class.**

```
timeSys.regDayChange([this](int prevDay,int nowDay){
    callSomeInternalFunction();
});
```

*Error i get:*

```
no suitable conversion function from "lambda [](int prevDay, int nowDay)->void" to "dayChangeFunc"
```

**How could i define my lambda to be able to capture the 'this' pointer?**

******** **EDIT: SOLVED** ********

Here are the modifications:

I had to define my lambda function type like this:

```
using dayChangeFunc = std::function<void(int, int)>;
```

Define the function pointer register function like this:

```
void regDayChange(dayChangeFunc cb);
```

And rewrite the declaration like this:

```
/*
*   Registering a day change function.
*   Maximum function pointer count is MAX_CB_CHANGE_FUNCTIONS ( see timeSys.h )
*/
void TimeSystem::regDayChange( dayChangeFunc cb ){
    if( currDayCbIndex >= MAX_CB_CHANGE_FUNCTIONS ){
        if(isDebugOn){
            debug.print(DEBUG_WARN,"[Time_sys] - Can not register an other day change function.\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    dayChangeFunctions[currDayCbIndex] = cb;
    currDayCbIndex++;
}
```

And now i can use it in any class like this:

```
class SampleClass(){
  private:
     int exampleCounter = 0;
  public:
    void init(){
      TimeSystem timeSys;
      timeSys.regDayChange([this](int prevDay,int nowDay){
        Serial.printf("Day changed from prev: %d to now: %d\n",prevDay,nowDay);
        exampleCounter++;
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your c++ standard?

Comment: PlatformIO standard AFAIK is C++11

Comment: Change the callback type to `std::function<void(int, int)>`.

Comment: Like this? typedef std::function<void(int, int)>;

Comment: I got the following error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]

Comment: You forgot to name the type. `using dayChangeFunc = std::function<void(int, int)>;`, or `typedef std::function<void(int, int)> dayChangeFunc;`. (Hardly anyone uses `typedef` these days.)

Comment: How would it look like as a function parameter? This does not work now:

Comment: void TimeSystem::regDayChange(void (*dayChangeFunc)(int prevDay,int nowDay))

Comment: declaration is incompatible with "void TimeSystem::regDayChange(dayChangeFunc)"

Comment: It would look the same as any other type; `void TimeSystem::regDayChange(dayChangeFunc func);`. (You confused yourself by using the same name for the parameter as for the type alias; normally one would have written exactly this even with your type alias.)

Comment: My definition looks like this: void regDayChange(dayChangeFunc); and my declaration looks like this: void TimeSystem::regDayChange(void (*dayChangeFunc)(int prevDay,int nowDay)){} but it does not work. The array of these function pointers are okay with that type

Comment: Oh it is compiled. Thank you very much!! Can you post it as a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the callback type to `std::function<void(int, int)>`

`using dayChangeFunc = std::function<void(int, int)>;`

or

`typedef std::function<void(int, int)> dayChangeFunc;`

and change the function prototype,

`void TimeSystem::regDayChange(dayChangeFunc func)`.

(If you had used your type alias consistently you wouldn't have needed to change the prototype, only the alias itself. Type aliases are most useful if you use them.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!
Do you recommend the using keyword or typedef one?

Comment: Use `using`. Almost nobody uses `typedef` these days, and there are even situations when you can't. Being consistent is a Good Thing.

Comment: Thank you! I will read about using a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda function that captures anything cannot be converted to a function pointer. You need to pass a pointer manually, or need to have a 'pool' of functions, each storing the current `this` pointer globally.

Comment: Can i use an std::function for it somehow?

Comment: @Dr.Random No, unless you change it on the callback as well. `std::function` also needs a pointer. What you're asking for simply doesn't work within c++.

Comment: @lorro What pointer would a `this`-capturing lambda need?

Comment: The entire class which calls it.

Comment: I'm registering a callback function inside various classes and want to do class related things inside the callback.

Comment: I solved it with the help of @molbdnilo